# Blazor Server Side: Load blazor.server.js in a static html page

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am attempting to load a blazor spa inside a static web page hosted in a different web service. I am using the Visual Studio Code extension **Live Server** to host the following static html file. I'm using a generic out-of-the-box blazor server side project for my example.

My problem is that the blazor.server.js loads and attempts to establish a connection but I get two console errors following the connection establishing.

- Error: The circuit failed to initialize.
- Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed.
- [screenshot of the two errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01lM9.png)

I'm no sure how to proceed with getting the actual app to load correctly. Any advice, suggestions, and/or answers are appreciated.

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>AAH.FirstAvailable.Client</title>
        <base href="http://localhost:5083/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:5083/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link href="http://localhost:5083/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="http://localhost:5083/AAH.FirstAvailable.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </header>
    <body>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

        <script src="http://localhost:5083/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the initial page must load from the same site as the Blazor Hub.  Think of the security issues running a Blazor App from one site into the Blazor Hub on another raises.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Could you elaborate on what security issues you see? I personally don't see the issue. Wouldn't it be the same as consuming blazor as a component / widget?